# Difference between "Relative to Group" vs "Relative to Project" in Xcode

Tags: xcode, file, structure

I'm fixing folder structure in my project and I wanted to know the different between "Relative to Group" vs "Relative to Project" I heard there can be some issues with "Relative to Group" when working with CI. I want to know whether to convert all my files and folders to "Relative to Group" or "Relative to Project"

Comment: In modern Xcode "Group" is usually the same as "Folder". "Relative to Group" is then "Relative to Folder" and it is generally the simplest option. The only exception is when your groups don't match your folders.

Answer (score 2):

"Relative to Group" is the default choice. By the past there could be some strange issues related to the fact that a group didn't necessary have an equivalent folder on disk. Nowaday when you create a group, a folder is automatically created too, so it becomes difficult to have this kind of problem. So I don't see any reason not to use the default behavior.